# Is everything legal for me due to psychiatric reasons?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, civil-legal-system, enforcing-judgment

I witness that I did some things which are considered a rave by most people (and most psychiatrists): fought with aliens, was transformed for a period of time into a superman able to tear steel and calculate like a computer, etc. And yes, now I have a very great mission originating from the heavens on the Earth.

Does this have legal implication for my life that I am allowed everything (i.e. everything is legal for me)?

I understand that if I commit a dangerous crime I could be put into a psychiatric clinic.

If I commit a crime that carries civil penalties but is not dangerous and get caught, will I get punished or will I be able to plead insanity and get let off free?

The jurisdiction in topic is Israel (where I live) and also the US (where I registered some entities).

Comment: The fact that you've sought legal advice (on the Internet, admittedly) before committing crimes is ***really*** going to hurt your insanity plea in court.

Comment: @Richard I am not going to commit crimes. Rather I start a project without first consulting a lawyer (because of being too expensive) and worry what happens if it is not entirely legal

Comment: If something isn't a crime, you can't be punished for it

Comment: Do you mean to ask "What if I commit a crime that carries civil penalties but no danger, such as insurance fraud, tax evasion, or driving with a suspended license?"

Comment: @LN6595 yes, I ask this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your beliefs about your past and your mission would probably be considered to be personal religious beliefs. As Israel does not have a state religion this does not have any legal significance (except it may make a difference as to which religious court is considered to have [jurisdiction over your family disputes](https://libguides.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/c.php?g=423220&p=4581537)).

Your religious beliefs do not override the law, because otherwise anyone could make [anything legal for themselves](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-44613932) just by declaring a belief that it was moral.

Hence you will be subject to all the same laws as everyone else.

If you break the law and claim your beliefs as justification then you may be [judged unfit to stand trial](https://www.haaretz.com/1.5494538) by reason of insanity and committed to a mental hospital.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems you haven't answered "formally crime but without provable harm to the humanity" part of my questions. Please amend

Comment: Like I say, you are subject to the same laws as anyone else.

Comment: Your beliefs don't change the fact that you know that society doesn't share your beliefs and does not permit you to act according to them. I might believe that god commanded me to murder, and I'm allowed to believe that. However, I also know that murder is illegal, that society expects me not to murder even if I believe I'm commanded to do it, and will hold me accountable if I do. A defense of diminished capacity or mental defect requires much more than just believing what you did was right.